# Create a branch from branch x, merge branch x to its parent branch and delete it. What happens to the created branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

My branch structure is this way:

```
---master---feature(commit-x)---task1(commit-y)---task2---
```

Since `task1` is complete, I want to merge the branch to the `feature` branch and delete it.

What happens to the branch `task2` in such a case?

I think the structure will be:

```
---master---(commit-x)---(commit-y)---task2---
                 |
                 |---feature(merged on task1)
```

But, then later on completion of `task2`, I would like to merge it on the `feature`  branch.

How can I accomplish that, please suggest?

Comment: Related: [What exactly do we mean by “branch”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)

Answer (score 0):

> What happens to the branch `task2` in such a case?

Nothing. `task2` will remain pointing to the same commit it was pointing before. In fact, `task1` will also be unchanged and will point to the same place. Only `feature` will change (it will have a new commit with the merged contents).

> But, then later on completion of `task2`, I would like to merge it on the `feature` branch.

Merge `task2` into `feature` the same way you did with `task1`. Again, both `task` branches will be unchanged, and `feature` will now contain the merge of `task2` after the merge of `task1`.

Comment: The trick is to understand that a branch is just a pointer to a revision. As such, they can be created, moved around, renamed or deleted and they do not affect the revisions they point to

Comment: The trick is to understand that the word "branch" means at least 2 different things in git. 1st, a branch is a chain of commits, a part of DAG. And 2nd a branch is a label to a commit. "Removing branch" removes the label but not the chain of commits.

Comment: @Winter If you unaccept and answer, please provide input why you do so.